# Кракозябры при выводе текста из БД Oracle с кодировкой win1251 с помощью PHP

Tags: oracle, кодировка, utf-8

Есть БД Oracle с кодировкой CL8MSWIN1251. При выводе данных из базы с помощью PHP получаю кракозябры. Соответственно, необходимо сменить кодировку на UTF8.

Собственно, сам код:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<?php 

// Данные базы данных Oracle для подключения к ней
$dbhost = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.1)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=BD)))"; 

// Имя пользователя базы данных Oracle
$dbusername = "admin";

// Пароль пользователя базы данных Oracle
$dbpass = "admin";

// Подключение к базе данных Oracle 
$dbconnect = oci_connect ($dbusername, $dbpass,$dbhost);

// Проверка подключения к базе данных Oracle$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
$res = oci_parse($dbconnect, 'select d01_f10 "Район"  ,d3g_f10  "Год"
from pr_f1_2017 @ aiss,(select d01_f3,d1o_f3,d3o_f3,D3G_F3,D3N_F3,d7k_f3
from f3_2017 @ aiss) ap
where    d01_f10 = ap.d01_f3(+)
          AND d3g_f10 = ap.d3g_f3(+);
oci_execute($res);

echo "<TABLE BORDER=1 class=table_price>  ";
echo "<TR>";

// отрисовка шапки таблицы
for ($i = 1; $i-1 < oci_num_fields($res); $i++) {
echo "<TH >";
echo oci_field_name($res,$i);
echo "</TH>";
}

// отрисовка и заполнение самой таблицы
while ($row = oci_fetch_row($res)) {
echo "<TR >";
for ($i = 0; $i < $fields=count($row); $i++) {
echo "<TD >".$row[$i]."</TD>";
}
echo "</TR>";
}
echo "</TR></TABLE>";  
oci_close($dbconnect)

?>
```

Пробовал несколько вариантов:

```
$dbconnect = oci_connect ($dbusername, $dbpass,$dbhost, 'UTF8');

select convert(d01_f3, \'UTF8\', \'CL8MSWIN1251\');
```

В последнем варианте сменить кодировку получилось, но так нужно на каждое поле отдельно прописывать. При этом не могу понять, как конвертировать шапку и заголовки - они так и остаются кракозябрами.

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> не помогает - словно этого условия и нет в коде.
```

Как правильно задать необходимую кодировку для всей таблицы, включая шапку и заголовки?!

Comment: попробуйте в connect передавать что то вроде `AL32UTF8` или поставьте переменную окружения NLS_LANG в `RUSSIAN.AL32UTF8`.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился следующим способом:

```
echo  iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8//IGNORE", trim(oci_field_name ($res,$i)));
```

где `oci_field_name ($res,$i)` то значение, которое необходимо перекодировать: либо текст, либо функция и т.д.